# Detect single coordinate in an array within an area in canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm trying to build a tower defense-like game in canvas, HTML. I'm currently working on the process of detecting coordinates within a range of a defense. Here's what I have worked out so far:

```
this.defensesInRangeArcher = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < buildArcherX.length; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < buildArcherY.length; i++) {
        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(buildArcherX[i] - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(buildArcherY[i] - this.y, 2)) <= arch.radius + 7) {
            this.defensesInRangeArcher += 1;
            this.attackByArcher = true;
        } else {
            this.attackByArcher = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So far in the following code, I have made it so that the "Defenses" could detect multiple coordinates within a range. "this" is able to detect the number of "defenses" in range but then arose a problem. Archers shoot one at a time but it affects all of "this" in range of the "defense". However, I don't want that so I was wondering how I could make it shoot one at a time.

I decided to use a global variable shown in the following code but had a bug in it.

```
this.defensesInRangeArcher = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < buildArcherX.length; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < buildArcherY.length; i++) {
        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(buildArcherX[i] - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(buildArcherY[i] - this.y, 2)) <= arch.radius + 7) {
            this.defensesInRangeArcher += 1;
            if (!v.singleAimArcher && !this.dead) {
                this.attackByArcher = true;
                v.singleAimArcher = true;
            }
        } else {
            this.attackByArcher = false;
            v.singleAimArcher = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It worked for the first defense it passed by, however not for the second one it passed by, so on.

I was wondering what kind of solution I could get to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: @Jarvis Anyone here have any suggestions?

Comment: Should I include more information?

Comment: What do you mean, 'detecting coordinates'? What, without showing any code, is the goal here?

Comment: @Howzieky The coordinates of the enemies in tower defense.